# Kotlin Returning Null cannot be a value of a non-null type

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to return a null value for a Kotlin function. It gives me the error `Null cannot be a value of a non-null type`.  But I want to be able to return null.  Although it looks the function can be void, it is an interface override and in this case there is no return value.

```
override fun call(jso: JSONObject): JSONObject {
    ...
    ...
    return null
}
```

I guess I can mark a variable nullable using `?`. But where can I put the `?` in this case?

Comment: use in JSONObject

Comment: I tried putting `?` everywhere, after JSONObject, after function name, before them.. nothing works..

Comment: check fun call(json: JSONObject): JSONObject? {
        return null
    }

Comment: Since you have the `override` modifier, you would also need to change the return type of the super class method!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the `?` after the return type:

```
override fun call(jso: JSONObject): JSONObject? {
    ...
    return null
}
```

Since you have the `override` modifier, you also need to change the return type of the super class method.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same problem I did in regards to null being able to be returned even though you changed the return type to say for example JSONObject? by getting an error:

> Return type is 'JSONObject?', which is not a subtype of overridden
>   public abstract...

Simply do this:

```
override fun call(jso: JSONObject): JSONObject {
    ...
    throw Exception("Error message!")
}
```